# Javascript and PHP: Problems with PushState

Tags: php, javascript

I'm using Pushstate to update the image id once a user clicks to go to next or prev image.

Currently, I have `window.history.pushState(null, null, './action=viewcomic&id=' + imgIndex);` which is working fine.

[image]

If I reload that url, however, it gives me a "Not Found" error:

[image]

I figured the reason for this is because I wasn't "pushState'ing" the site parameter in the URL... so when I go the next image, the url goes from:

```
http://www.hittingtreeswithsticks.com/?action=viewimage&site=comics&id=54
```

To:

```
http://www.hittingtreeswithsticks.com/action=viewcomic&id=55
```

So I tried to fix that by including the site parameter in the pushState as such:

```
var site = <?php echo $site ?>;
window.history.pushState(null, null, './action=viewcomic&site=' + site + '&id=' + imgIndex);
```

But now it won't even load the image.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Are you missing the `?`? have you tried `'./?action.....'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have the question mark prepending the "action" GET variable.

Comment: Everyone makes mistakes, no worries :p